# Rails Tutorial 8.2: Log in Log out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, railstutorial.org

Working through the Rails Tutorial and in chapter 8 I can't get one of my tests to pass.  Been checking around for hours... any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 2015-09-07     00:25:37 -0700]
test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1441610737.31s)
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash:         
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
    app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:8:in `create'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
    app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:8:in `create'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

22/22: [============] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.46288s
22 tests, 44 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

**users_login_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since originally posted, but I had exactly the same error and my problem was a typo (missing =) in 
**users.yml**

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <% User.digest('password') %>
```

where it should have been

```
michael:
name: Michael Example
email: michael@example.com
password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly my problem, you saved me 20 minutes of triage.

Answer (score 0):

@PraveenGeorge is correct - you need to back track and review your code at least since the last time the tests passed. Based on the fact that the content of the two files you've shared match to the tutorial, the problem lies elsewhere (and, unfortunately, out of sight from us on SO).

Perhaps it's in user.rb where you `def User.digest(string)` or in sessions_helper.rb?

Answer (score -1):

Dear @Travislogan : As the ruby on rails tutorial itself is self explanatory in most possible way, you might have missed some of the steps/code before you reached into the section 8.2. So please cross check all tests and your project code from at least the previous chapter to the current one , one more time.It will help you to find out the error in your code.

Comment: Thank you @PraveenGeorge, I have gone through my branch with the tutorial step by step several times, and cannot find the issue.  I did this prior to posting, I was hoping someone might catch something without me having to start the chapter anew. But alas...

Comment: @travislogan: Ok its very difficult sometimes to findout what went wrong, so I suggest you to switch back to the last branch where everything was working fine, and start working again with codes and test from there one more time, this may help you sometimes.